# Case in Sql group by query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a project in which I want to use Case to calculate price of product under specific `Reference` Number in SQL server.  Below is my Sql query

```
SELECT
    product AS Products,
    refNum AS Refrence,
    COUNT(id) AS Count 
FROM ProductPriceList 
GROUP BY
    refNum, product
```

By Executing Above query I get:

```
Product      Reference   Count
Product1     Ref08       24
Product2     Ref08       7
Product3     Ref07       32
Product2     Ref12       1
Product3     Ref12       18
Product1     Ref07       76  
Product1     Null        56
```

Can anyone guide me how to use `Case` statement in Sql query with `group by` statement to show price Below is the case:

```
if count < 10 then price 1
if count > 10 and < 100 then price 2
if count > 100 then price 3
```

I don't want to add a new table in my database.  I hope you can understand my query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You said in a comment below `don't want null value to be grouped`.  Then what is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's alternative (doesn't differ much from exisiting one though):

You can use your query in subquery and use `case` outside:

```
select product,
       --to get NULL values back
       case Reference when 'RefNull' then NULL else Reference end [Reference],
       case when [Count] < 10 then 1
            when [Count] between 10 and 100 then 2
            else 3 end [price]
from (
     SELECT product AS Products,
            --to allow also null values to be grouped
            coalesce(refNum, 'RefNull') AS Refrence,
            COUNT(id) AS Count 
    FROM ProductPriceList 
    GROUP BY coalesce(refNum, 'RefNull'), product
) [a]
```

Comment: Thanks it works but i forgot to add one thing i.e product with no refNum null, i have edited my code above

Comment: @PankashMann Normally gorup by excludes `NULL` values. See my updateed query.

Comment: don't want null value to be grouped , edited query shows same result as previous one

Comment: @PankashMann I think you do, that what you said. I again updated query, it had a bug :)

Answer (score 4):

I think a basic `CASE` expression can handle your requirement:

```
SELECT
    product AS Products,
    refNum AS Refrence,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(*) < 10 THEN 1
         WHEN COUNT(*) >= 10 AND COUNT(*) < 100 THEN 2
         ELSE 3 END AS price
FROM ProductPriceList 
GROUP BY
    product, refNum;
```

Not much to explain here, except that the `2` price case uses a bound which *includes* the count of 10 (since the `1` price case excludes it).

Comment: Thanks it works but i forgot to add one thing i.e product with no refNum null, i have edited my code above

Comment: @PankashMann Normally `NULL` would just be treated as any other value when grouping.  I don't see a problem.  Maybe you can add sample data to your question which addresses this.

Answer (score 1):

Dataset:

```
Create Table ProductPriceList 
(
 Product varchar(10)
,RefNum CHAR(5)
,Records Int
);

Insert into ProductPriceList
Values
 ('Product1','Ref08',24)
,('Product2','Ref08',7)
,('Product3','Ref07',32)
,('Product2','Ref12',1)
,('Product3','Ref12',18)
,('Product1','Ref07',76)
,('Product1', NULL, 56);

With RCTE AS
(
Select   Product
        ,RefNum
        ,Records
        ,1 RowNo
From ProductPriceList PPL
Union All
Select   Product
        ,RefNum
        ,Records
        ,RowNo + 1
From RCTE R
Where RowNo + 1 < Records
)
Insert Into ProductPriceList (Product, RefNum, Records)
Select Product, RefNum, Records
From RCTE
where Records > 1
```

Query to fetch desired result:

```
Select   Product
        ,RefNum 
        ,Case When Count(*) < 10 Then 1
              When Count(*)  Between 10 and 99 then 2
        Else 3 End Price
From ProductPriceList
Group By Product, RefNum
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/98e88/3/0)